# Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm working on a chating site and I've been getting this pesky error for a while now, really don't know what it could be. 
I have this Model class:

```
public class ChatModel : PageModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Espectators { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Chatters { get; set; }
    public string Mediator { get; set; }
    public Conversation Conversation{ get; set; }
    public Lazy<IConcurrentCaching> _cache { get; set; }

    public ChatModel()
    {
    }


    public ChatModel(string connString, string bulkTime, string username, ICollection<string> espectators = null, ICollection<string> chatters = null, string mediator = null, string conversationName = null)
    {
        //build the class, boring stuff
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

This model is part of a Razor page. 
This is my controller for the Chat view:

```
public class ChatController: Controller
{

    public ChatController()
    {

    }
    public IActionResult Chat(ChatModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And the call for the Controller action:

```
public IActionResult CreateChat(string username, string conversationName)
    {
        if (_cache.Value.Get<List<string>>("ChatList") == null)
        {
            _cache.Value.Set<List<string>>("ChatList", new List<string>(), 1440);
        }
        ChatModel model = new ChatModel(_op.Value.ConnectionString, _op.Value.BulkLoadCacheTimeInMinutes, username, conversationName: conversationName);
        model.Chatters.Add(username);
        return RedirectToAction("Chat","Chat", model);
    }
```

For some reason, when I call the controller method for the Chat view, it throws the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext'. Model bound complex types
>   must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless
>   constructor. Alternatively, set the 'HttpContext' property to a
>   non-null value in the 'Chatter.UI.Web.Views.Chat.ChatModel'
>   constructor.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext)

The weirdest thing is that I'm not even using HttpContext on the ChatModel class. I have tried using DI to inject the IHttpContextAccessor on my class (even though I don't see how that would help, but I've seen that as a solution online); it did't work. I've also tried to add a singleton on the startup for the HttpContext, but to no avail. Any ideas on what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of class is PageModel ?

Comment: Your `ChatModal` class is supposed to have default parameterless constructor only as far as I know

Comment: Why is the ChatModel a PageModel? Seems like you're mixing RazorPages and Mvc in a strange way

Comment: I am new to Razor pages, are the razor page models not interchangeable  with MVC models?

Answer (score 5):

You should not combine `PageModel` and `Controller`.

As the error indicates, Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. For `ChatModel` which inherits `PageModel` is `abstract` class.

Create a new separate class for use in `Controller` action.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace sucu1.Models
{
    public class LoginViewModel : Controller
    {

        public string? Mail { get; set; }
        public string? Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).